# open file in (.dtsx) format in visual studio 2010 after convert from 2005 to 2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssis

my problem is.. last time I have convert my whole project from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2010 and now my problem is I want open .dtsx file of it, but I cant find the way to open it.. anyone can tell me...thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This:**

You need the Business Intelligence Studio.It might be missing in your visual studio 2010.I comes in SP1 of Visual Studio 2010.Either you update your Visual Studio 2010 to SP1 or

**try with this link:**

[Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=3C856B93-369F-4C6F-9357-C35384179543&displaylang=en)

Comment: is that no other ways if I do not want to install this ?

Comment: @L3N-One more thing you can give a try. What you need to do is to go into BIDS(Business Intelligence Development Studio) and start a new SSIS project.  (I would give it a name that is meaningful and if the DTSX file already has one, use that one.)  Once you have started it, you can right click on the SSIS Packages line and add an existing package.  Once you have done that, you can edit the package.

Comment: You can vote up/mark it an answer if my answer solved your problem